# Oh my God, Oh my Lord, Oh my Gosh

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, euphemisms, minced-oaths

What are the differences between them? Is there a cultural and/or social interference?

Do young people say `"Oh my Gosh"` more than others?

Comment: See [bowdlerize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bowdlerize?q=bowdlerise)

Comment: 'Young people' don't seem to care much anymore. 'Oh my god' seems more common that 'oh my gosh'. Only old ladies drinking tea say 'oh my lord'.

Comment: and for those who don't like to take the name of the Lord their God in vain, there's (or, there *was*) always ["Oh, my sainted aunt!"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Oh+my+sainted+aunt%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22Oh%2C+my+sainted+aunt!%22&tbm=bks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou_shalt_not_take_the_name_of_the_Lord_thy_God_in_vain) - hence the Gosh for God.

Also it is considered not really swearing when you use Gosh

Same idea when using "chips" instead of "shit" - it sounds the same but is less offensive to parents

@Matt just reminded me of a word that can be used for this

[Bowdlerise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bowdlerize?q=)

> remove material that is considered improper or offensive from (a text or account), especially with the result that the text becomes weaker or less effective:

And @DK pointed to the better suggestion of [Minced Oaths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath)<sub>Wikipedia</sub>

> A minced oath is a euphemistic expression formed by misspelling, mispronouncing, or replacing a part of a profane, blasphemous, or taboo term to reduce the original term's objectionable characteristics. Some examples include gosh instead of god, darn or dang for damn, and heck for hell.

Comment: 'cheese and rice', 'shut the front door', 'dang'.

Comment: I sometimes do "FUgods sake"

Comment: this answer may also be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/211050/97169